# Configure Oracle for Spring-xd

Tags: oracle, spring-xd

I am trying to run spring-xd in distributed mode and have to use Oracle DB. When I started xd-admin, it failed with the following error:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/xd/batch/schema/registry-schema-oracle.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Spring XD guide says

> Until full schema support is added for Oracle, Sybase and other database, you will need to put a .jar file in the xd/lib directory that contains the equivalent functionality as these DDL scripts.

I created "registry-schema-oracle.sql" and "registry-schema-drop-oracle.sql", packed them in a jar file called "oracle_ddl.jar", and put the jar file under $XD_HOME/xd/lib/, but the problem is still the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have both the sql files under this package:

org/springframework/xd/batch/schema

Comment: Duh, why didn't I think of that? Thanks for the tip! Perhaps the XD Guide should be a bit clearer

Comment: Glad to know that. Would you mind pushing a PR with the schema sql files that support Oracle DB? thanks!

Comment: Hi Khoa, Thank you for the PR. I have re-opened the JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-1341 and we will merge your PR shortly after the review.

Comment: @KhoaNguyen The DDL and other required configuration changes are added to spring-xd. Thanks again for the help!        https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/commit/e569c11254ba92dd7bb43ad71e926e5967c14899